# checkbox is not working properly in html how to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this checkbox input that I want it to call a function when its clicked

```
      <div class="checkbox theme-search-results-sidebar-section-checkbox-list-item">
        <label class="icheck-label">
          <input class="icheck" type="checkbox" onclick="system()">
          <span class="icheck-title" >
          system is good
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
```

I tried different methods the only way that I got it to work was by using the onclick on the span but that would not work if the box gets checked!

Can anyone help me with this?

I can't change the layout because I have a fixed HTML that is like this for a lot of checkboxes.

Comment: Your checkbox is clickable, and the function triggers on click. What "*is not working properly*"?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be working the way you describe it with a simple "system()" function. The problem may be in your system() function.

```js
function system(){
  console.log("inside system")
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox theme-search-results-sidebar-section-checkbox-list-item">
        <label class="icheck-label">
          <input class="icheck" type="checkbox" onclick="system()">
          <span class="icheck-title" >
          system is good
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
```

Comment: it works here because the iCheck plugin class are not defined, I searched it up and found the documentation and the function for it to work is ''' $('#system').on('ifChanged', function(event){
  alert(event.type + ' callback');
}); '''

Answer (score 0):

Try this. First select the check box in JavaScript:

`const $checkbox = document.querySelector('.icheck')`;

Then add a click event listener to it:

```
$checkbox.addEventListener('click', system);
```

This will run system when it is clicked.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work, the function is $('#system').on('ifChanged', function(event){
  alert(event.type + ' callback');
});